# Regularity for the Feasible region

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have this problem

$min -x +y $

$x-y^2\leq0 $

$\frac {(x-1)^2}{4} +y^2 \leq 1$

$y \geq -1/2$

- Say if the feasible region is regular or not, analitically.

I know that to check the KKT conditions I have to check the regularity condition in a given point $x_0$, but what does it mean for the "feasible region"? What I have to do?